# Load PartialView with using jquery Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, html.dropdownlistfor

PartialView

```
@model OsosYeni23072012.Models.TblMeters
<h3>
    Model.customer_name
</h3>
<h3>
    Model.meter_name
</h3>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MeterInfoPartial(string meter_id)
{
    int _meter_id = Int32.Parse(meter_id);
    var _meter = entity.TblMeters.Where(x => x.sno == _meter_id).FirstOrDefault();

    return PartialView("MeterInfoPartial", _meter);
}
```

Razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("sno", new SelectList(Model, "sno", "meter_name"), "-- Select Meter --", new { id = "meters"})

@Html.Partial("MeterInfoPartial")
```

I want to load partial view, if dropdownlist change. But I dont know How can I do this. I cant find any example about this. I do this with actionlink. But I did not with dropdown before.

controller parameter `meter_id` equals dropdownlist selectedvalue.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the model loaded on the initial page load? if the model is not instantiated and initialized won't it cause an exception. Or are you loading a partial view with a record from when the page is loaded the first time? Sorry for any incorrect vernacular; I am new to this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `.change()` event of the dropdown and then trigger an AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#meters').change(function() {
            var meterId = $(this).val();
            if (meterId && meterId != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("MeterInfoPartial")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { meter_id: meterId }
                }).done(function(result) {
                        $('#container').html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and then you would wrap the partial with a div given an id:

```
<div id="container">
    @Html.Partial("MeterInfoPartial")
</div>
```

Also why are you parsing in your controller action, leave this to the model binder:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MeterInfoPartial(int meter_id)
{
    var meter = entity.TblMeters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.sno == meter_id);
    return PartialView(meter);
}
```

Be careful with `FirstOrDefault` because if it doesn't find a matching record in your database given the `meter_id` it will return `null` and your partial will crash when you attempt to access the model.

Comment: Thanks. Should I check if the return is null in the view?

Comment: No, you should do that in your controller action. You could return a JSON response in this case so that the success AJAX handler is able to detect this case and act accordingly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `$('#container').html(result);` this will fills the partial view in that container rite ?. So is it required for to call the corresponding action that you mentioned after this line `then you would wrap the partial with a div given an id:` .

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - is the `@Html.Partial` required? Assuming the Partial view has the same name as the controller action (MeterInfoPartial in this case), it seems to work okay without it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov what if partial view parameter is viewmodel with many field not just single string/int parameter??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#addnews').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddNews", "Manage")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                }).done(function(result){
                    $('#containera').html(result);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```